# SQL check if timestamp is greater than 24 hours from now (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

How to check if timestamp is greater than 24 hours from now with mysql?

```
DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `time` = ?
```

Update: date format — 2013-10-24 13:33:23

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try out this Query:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE date >= now() + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Feel free to ask

Comment: I tried: DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `time` > NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
And other versions, but it doens't work ;(.
Date format: 2013-10-24 13:33:23

Comment: @newUser,
 Just now i have created your Solution,
 According to me Syntax almost Correct only.

 `SELECT * FROM supportContacts WHERE datetime >= NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY`

You can check for reference : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/057b2/10

Comment: I have created table and Checking data is greater than 24 hours from now.

`CREATE TABLE supportContacts 
 (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     type varchar(20), 
     details varchar(30),datetime date
    );

INSERT INTO supportContacts
(type, details,datetime)
VALUES
('Twitter', '@sqlfiddle',now()),
('Twitter', '@sqlfiddle',now() + interval 1 day),
('Twitter', '@sqlfiddle',now() + interval 2 day);`


Query for :

`SELECT * FROM supportContacts WHERE datetime >= NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Comment: MySQl version i have tested: 5.5.32.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `time` >= (NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

or try this:

```
DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `time` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

or try this:

```
DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `time` >=  curdate() + interval 1 day
```

here is a link with some function mysql to manage time
[**DOCUMENTATION**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
DELETE FROM `users` 
WHERE `time` >= TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, 1, NOW());
```

[`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) returns the current date and time.

[`TIMESTAMPADD(unit,interval_expression)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd) adds one day to the current date and time.